# SQL Server Log: The database 'master4IDR' is marked RESTORING

Tags: sql-server-2005

Why SQL Server log showing following message. I am dead sure, there is no such db on our production server naming "master4IDR"

{The database 'master4IDR' is marked RESTORING and is in a state that does not allow recovery to be run.}

Comment: are you using Symantec BackupExec or  Veritas BackExec or may be other Backup tools they create snapshot backups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using Symantec BackupExec check out this article

[How to disable the creation of the $IDR file when backing up a Microsoft SQL server](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH49015)